# iptables for routing 8080 and 8443 to 80 and 443 respectively

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

I have the below script that creates my iptables. How can I make it so if I access IP_ADDR:8080 or :8443 it routes to 80 or 443 respectively?

```
#!/bin/bash

# Delete all existing rules
iptables -F

# Set default chain policies
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP

# Allow loopback access
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

  # Allow inbound SSH
  iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
  iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

  # Allow outbound DNS
  iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 53 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
  iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --sport 53 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

  # Allow outbound HTTP
  iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
  iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --sport 80 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

  # Allow outbound HTTPS
  iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
  iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --sport 443 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

  # Allow outbound SMTP
  iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 587 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
  iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --sport 587 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really specify whether you want to translate:
(Inside) 80 -> (Outside) 8080 or the other way around.

Assuming you want to run the httpd on your system to listen on 8080 and 8443 to service external user traffic on 80 and  443 (thereby avoiding the problem of having to run as root to open those ports < 1025) you want to use the NAT feature of iptables:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

and do the same for 443 -> 8443

Comment: Ooops! Yes, these are inbound requests to the server. So someone going to IP_ADDR:8080 would be redirected to IP_ADDR:80 (web site)

Comment: OK then just reverse the port values on what I typed above.

Comment: iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j REDIRECT --to-port 80

Comment: Sorry, what I wrote was wrong. The web gui is only accessible via 8080, but I want it accessible via 80.

Comment: It works. The only thing is the web gui redirects those who use http to https but it adds the 8443 at the end. Not a big deal.  If I go directly to https:// it works without the 8443 at the end.